# Couldn't execute postMethod: Javax.net.ssl.SslException: Revoked by CRL

Tags: java, ssl, https, keystore

I have a POST method:

```
PostMethod post = new PostMethod(myPostUrl);
```

Then I execute the `PostMethod`:

```
httpClient.executeMethod(post);
```

When I try to execute it, I get an exception such as:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: Revoked by CRL (cached response)
```

What causes this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> java.security.cert.CertificateException: Revoked by CRL (cached response)

It's all in the error message: the certificate of the server you're trying to contact has been revoked and is therefore no longer valid.

Certificates can revoked during the course of their normal validity period (the notBefore and notAfter timestamps with which they are issued) for a number of reasons. A well configured SSL/TLS client should generally check with the CA for revocation if possible. This check was performed against the CRL here, and it appears the CA has revoked the certificate of the server you're trying to connect to. The genuine server should present a certificate that has not been revoked.

Comment: I try to execute post method with wget command without checking certificate, and this is working. How to turn off certificate checking?

Comment: Disabling certificate verification is generally a bad idea. Can't you get the person running this server to fix it instead?

Comment: The problem is solved. Certificate was really revoked by CA. I created a new certificate and program has worked.

Answer (score 0):

The server certificate has been revoked. The operation you were attempting is insecure. The system saved you.